# How to code the exception for a column in excel using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel-automation

#### Sample data:

```
|   | Status                  | Failed | In Progress | Passed | Untested |
|---|-------------------------|--------|-------------|--------|----------|
| 2 | P0 Dry Run - 13/02/18   | 2.0    |             | 143.0  | 5.0      |
| 3 | P1 Test Plan - 06/02/18 | 4.0    |             | 247.0  | 367.0    |
| 4 | P2 Test plan - 03/01/18 | 22.0   | 2.0         | 496.0  | 54.0     |
```

#### Code:

```
msft = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\gomathis\\Downloads\\week_071.csv") 
msft = msft[['Passed', 'Failed', 'Blocked', 'In Progress', 'Not_Implemented', 'Not Applicable', 'Clarification Opened', 'Untested']]
msft.to_csv("C:\\Users\\gomathis\\Downloads\\week_072.csv")
```

#### Error:

```
KeyError: "['Blocked'] not in index"
```

#### Expected result:

I need an exception for a column which may not be available now but in future it may come. So help me accordingly to solve this.

Comment: what do you want to do for the columns which are not in your csv file?

Comment: Yes exactly, since which we may not available now but in future it will be available.

Comment: what do you want to do if your csv file does not have `Blocked` column? you want the output dataframe with same column as uploaded csv file ?

Comment: Yes, I need Blocked column even it is not in the uploaded csv file

Comment: what do you want to fill in `Blocked` colunm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `csv.DictReader.fieldnames` attribute, figure out what columns are present in your CSV, and then find the intersection of those.

First, specify the columns you want.

```
columns = ['Passed', 
           'Failed', 
           'Blocked', 
           'In Progress', 
           'Not_Implemented', 
           'Not Applicable', 
           'Clarification Opened', 
           'Untested']

path = "C:\\Users\\gomathis\\Downloads\\week_071.csv"   # we'll use this later
```

Next, use the `csv.DictReader` to read the CSV's headers (this does NOT read the entire file!).

```
import csv
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    df_columns = reader.fieldnames
```

Now, find the set intersection, and pass it to `usecols` in `pd.read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=set(columns).intersection(df_columns))
```

Finally, to fill in missing columns, take the set difference and call `df.assign`:

```
df = df.assign(**dict.fromkeys(set(columns).difference(df_columns), np.nan))
```

Comment: `TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_cols'
`

Comment: @gomathisubramanian Sorry, it's "usecols", without the underscore.

Comment: @pyd Does it make sense to keep a column that does not exist?

Comment: I think he wants to fill with some other values for the columns that does not exist

Comment: @pyd Maybe, maybe not. OP's question isn't very clear on that aspect, so I'll wait for their response :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I need a Blocked which doesn't exist in my data, but in the future it may need  for me align the columns in particular order that I need to display

Comment: Yes, I don't have the value of blocked,

Comment: @gomathisubramanian Okay, thank you, that was helpful. I've added an edit at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @pyd You were right in the end, so I've fixed it :)

Comment: what does `**dict.fromkeys()` do ? pls explain

Comment: @pyd Try running this: `dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b', 'c'], np.nan)` it generates a dictionary of all keys with the same value (np.nan). Then, just unpack the dictionary when passing it to `df.assign`.

Comment: will it works when i have a value in blocked column. Say if the `Blocked` has value `2` will  it print value 2 or it will show the `nan` values